# having difficulty converting requests.models.Response to scrapy.selector.unified.Selector

Tags: scrapy

This code

```
import requests
url = 'https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html'
response = requests.get(url)
```

gets me a `requests.models.Response` instance, from which I can extract data with scrapy

```
from scrapy import Selector
sel = Selector(response=response)
sel.xpath('//div')
```

[A post gives a great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690016/12214867) way to access a website. Here is just part of it.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.zhihu.com/api/v4/columns/wangzhenotes/items', headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

With that approach, I got the content from that site.

However, the same code cannot extract data from the Response instance

```
sel = Selector(response=response)
len(sel.xpath('//div'))
```

I just got 0. How do I fix this?

Comment: ```sel = Selector(response=response)``` what is response here? is it response for this request -  ```response = requests.get('https://www.zhihu.com/api/v4/columns/wangzhenotes/items', headers=headers)```?

Comment: @Roman Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of this request

`response = requests.get('https://www.zhihu.com/api/v4/columns/wangzhenotes/items', headers=headers)`

is JSON object, sure it does not contain any div

to get the required information you have to parse that JSON

```
response = requests.get('https://www.zhihu.com/api/v4/columns/wangzhenotes/items', headers=headers)
data = response.json()['data']
```

then you need to loop through the `data` list and take fields which you need

again, if you want yo use scrapy, you can make requests to url `https://www.zhihu.com/api/v4/columns/wangzhenotes/items`

and then in `parse` method read response as JSON:

`j_obj = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())`